# Subscribe to a topic to receive inbound messages (PublishSubscribeChannel)

Tags: integration

We are exploring an integration where an status update from order processing application has to be consumed by multiple applications.

The integration pattern we identified to be suited best for us is Publish-Subscribe Channel (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html).

In this scenario, the Order processing application will publish the order status to an intergration layer (middleware or messaging queues), where in the consumer application (Salesforce is one of them) will need to subscribe to the integration layer (a topic or a queue) to receive the status when published.

I have explored push topics but it seems to me that they might be used for publishing the data from Salesforce to external systems but not the other way around.

Is there any mechanism in Salesforce to subscribe to a queue or topic in integration layer to receive the updates in real time?